# How to convert date and time like timeline in android?

Tags: android, date, time, format

I am learning format date and time in android, I want to try to convert the date and time as the timeline ... ?
example:

```
String current_date = "2013-10-07 20:57:20";

String val_date1 = "2013-10-07 20:57:20";
String val_date2 = "2013-10-07 19:57:20";
String val_date3 = "2013-10-07 17:57:20";
String val_date4 = "2013-09-07 20:57:20";
```

above date and adjusted **CURRENT_DATE** converted and the results such as these:

```
String val_date1_after_formated = "just now";
String val_date2_after_formated = "1h";
String val_date3_after_formated = "3h";
String val_date4_after_formated = "1d";
```

how to convert date with the program? I hope anyone can help me. Sorry if my English is not good ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a function that should do the job

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
int[] steps = {1,60,3600,3600*24};
String[] names = {"seconds","minutes","hours","days"};

//...

public String formatDelay(String date){
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(date);
        Long stamp = d.getTime()/1000;
        Long now = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;         
        Long dif = now - stamp;

        if(stamp > now) return "";

        for(int i=0;i<steps.length;i++){
            if(dif<steps[i]){
                String output = Long.toString(dif/steps[i-1])+" "+names[i-1];
                return output;
            }
        }       

        return Long.toString(dif/steps[3])+" "+names[3];


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Works great if you add a check for 0s (0-999 ms)
if(dif == 0) return "0s"; just below stamp>now or change the stamp>now to stamp>=now depending on what you want

Answer (score 1):

`formatDuration` might be good for this:

```
public String getDuration(long time) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils.formatDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() - date, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now to get the `long time` you need to parse the input dates (maybe using `SimpleDateFormat`).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
long date = sdf.parse("2013-10-07 20:57:20").getTime();
String duration = getDuration(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but to get the current time use this. Returns in milliseconds.

```
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

To format it to a time date-time use this code.

```
long loadDate = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(loadDate));
```